# Singular Value Decomposition of $A^{T}A$

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

How to show that the singular values of $A^{T}A$ are $σ_{1}^{2},...,σ_{n}^{2}$, and thus $∥A^{T}A∥_{2}$ = $σ_{max}^{2}$.
In order to do this I have to find a singular vale decomposition for $A^{T}A$ ?

Comment: Can you work out $A^TA$, using the fact that $U$ has orthonormal columns? Then look at the result carefully.

Comment: To help you further : you can compute $A^TA$ explicitely in terms of the matrices in the SVD decomposition of $A$.

Comment: since U has orthonormal columns would it mean that it would be  $Σ^{T}ΣV^{T}V$

Comment: How do you achieve this ? You have the good matrices left but the order is compltely wrong. Recall that $(CD)^T=D^TC^T$ and $CD \ne DC$ in general.

Comment: it would be this $A^{T}A=V(Σ^{T}Σ)V^{T}$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
A^TA=(U\Sigma V^T)^T(U\Sigma V^T=V\Sigma^TU^TU\Sigma V^T=V(\Sigma^T\Sigma)V^T
$$
and that $\Sigma^T\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries on the diagonal. Thus this is a singular value decomposition of $A^TA$. The entries on the diagonal of $\Sigma^T\Sigma$ are $\sigma_i^2$, where $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$ are the singular values of $A$.

Recall that the singular value decomposition is essentially unique, in the sense that if $A=U_1\Sigma_1V_1^T=U_2\Sigma_2V_2^T$, with $\Sigma$ (pseudo)-diagonal with nonnegative entries and $U_1,U_2,V_1,V_2$ are orthogonal, then $\Sigma_1$ equals $\Sigma_2$ up to permutation of the (pseudo-)diagonal elements. The orthogonal matrices are not unique, though.